# Which java Collection fits better with frequent object updates from a Poll server

Tags: java, collections

I have a defined group of 5 Parkings. I receive from a poll server every 20 seconds new values of these parkings(Id, Number of available places, etc)

I am wondering which java collection, in terms of performance and "best practices" allows me to keep only my 5 parkings at a time and not having duplicated parkings and then to retrieve a parking by Id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the maps. HashMap using id as key.

Comment: If updates were spaced 20 milliseconds apart, or if they contained information about billions of parking lots, efficiency would be a thing to discuss. With updates every 20 seconds, you can keep your collection in a cloud or on a file system, and code it as inefficiently as you could imagine, and despite all that it is going to perform well :)

Comment: you're probably right..I know it's not really a big deal, but hey...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are no duplicate `Id` keys, then any standard implementation of the [`Map` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) will do. You can retrieve a value by its key, and inserting a value for an existing key will replace the old value, so that no duplicate keys exist.

That said, [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is the most performant of the standard `Map` implementations, provided that your only requirement is the protection against duplicate keys. [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) additionally provides iteration with a predictable order, with only a minimal performance hit. [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) has a higher complexity, and thus lower performance, but it constantly keeps all entries sorted based on their keys.